# Camunda DelegateExecution Event

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I am new to Camunda.I am trying to trigger a event in spring boot application when I perform manual action like retry from Camunda BPM UI.
For that I am using Eventlistner.

`@EventListener Public void onExecutionEvent(DelegateEvent executionDelegate){ // printing executionDelegate here }`

I need the information present in executionDelegate object.But on printing it is giving me hash value.
Do anybody have complete object information as there are lot of class and interfaces in this Class.It would you be helpful if i am able to get a sample of complete object I information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The hash value is the default result of the "toString()"  method which every class in java implements by default (by extending "Object").

The fact that you see a hash value means, that the DelegateEvent does not overwrite this method in way you maybe used to.

So the question is: what do you want to know from the delegateExecution? MOst often, you will be interested in the process variables ... you can just print out the result of the "getVariables()" method ...

If you want to learn more about the class and its values, put a break point in your eventListener method, start spring boot in debug mode and use the inspect/evaluate code feature of whatever IDE you use to just play around and get familiar.

Comment: Thanks for the help.As you may be aware that we can do operation like modify variables ,add variables or perform retry etc.There are two ways of doing it ,either by Camunda UI or Rest API.I wanted to know if there is any values in delegateExecution that would differentiate  whether this operation are performed using API or Camunda UI.That is why I needed information  on delegateExecution.

Comment: Look for get/set Variable